# Lower bound on $| \lceil a \rfloor b- a\lceil b \rfloor|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $\lceil  a \rfloor$ be the nearest integer function. Is there a nice lower bound on the expression:
\begin{align}
| \lceil  a \rfloor b- a\lceil  b \rfloor|
\end{align}
Thank you

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: I am doing the some research and stumbled on this

Comment: actually I am trying to solve a problem I posted earlier and this is one of the solutions. I am just trying to find a nice lower bound. The previous post can be found here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915168/minimum-of-az-x-bz-y

Comment: The obvious lower bound $0$ is sharp, for example $a = 3+\frac{1}{4}$ and $b = 4+\frac{1}{3}$. Are you maybe looking for an upper bound?

Comment: But, it's not always 0. Yes, I would like to bound it from above and below.

Comment: ^A much easier example is found by just using integers.

Comment: @Nishant one of the few examples where integers make the problem easier^^

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for messing things up!

**EDIT:** The following is not the requride solution, I think the a bound could  rather be achieved by finding $$|\lceil a \rfloor b - a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq \min\limits_{(x,y)\in [-0.5,0.5]^2} |(a+x)b-a(b+y)| $$

**EDIT2:** No this is not the term we search for, since it will result in $0$ in any way.

**EDIT3:**

One of the following must be true:

$$|\lceil a\rfloor b-a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq | \lfloor a \rfloor b - a \lceil b \rceil | $$

$$|\lceil a\rfloor b-a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq | \lfloor a \rfloor b - a \lfloor b \rfloor| $$

$$|\lceil a\rfloor b-a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq | \lceil a \rceil b - a \lceil b \rceil| $$

$$|\lceil a\rfloor b-a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq | \lceil a \rceil b - a \lfloor b \rfloor| $$

So you can just take the minimum of those as a lower bound (if you are lazy) or think about under which assumptions which ones of those hold. (because I am lazy=) I think you can use the same tactics for finding an upper bound (by just writing $\geq$ insted of $\leq$ or vice versa)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you

Comment: Question: can a number 0.5 be improved?

Comment: I guess not since it comes from the definition of nearest integer function?

Comment: I think this lower bound is wrong. Consider, $a=5.2$ and $b=3.3$.  Then $| \lceil 5.2 \rfloor 3.3-\lceil 3.3 \rfloor 5.2|=|5*3.3-3*5.2|=|15.6-16.5|=0.9$. But $0.5|a-b|=0.5|5.2-3.3|=0.5|1.9|=0.95$.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right! I think the correct version of my approach would be $|\lceil a \rfloor b - a \lceil b \rfloor | \geq \min\limits_{(x,y)\in [-0.5,0.5]^2} |(a+x)b-a(b+y)|$ but I am not yet sure how to find that.

Comment: No problem. This is still better than what I had before. Could you please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you already see the ideas with $\lfloor \rfloor$ and $\lceil
\rceil$? It is basically just reformulating your problem but not a solution. The idea with $\min$ does not work since it will always yield 0 as lower bound.

Comment: No I didn't, could you elaborate?

Comment: It is basically the same argument again, but this time it is correct=) BUT you do not get such a nice expression.

Comment: So I would look at $| \lceil a \rceil b-\lceil b \rceil a|$, right?