# Minimum of $f(x,y)=|ax-by|$ subject to box constraints

Tags: optimization

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x, y} {\text{minimize}} & f(x,y) := | a x - b y | \\ \text{subject to} & 0 \le x \le C_1 \\ & 0 \le y \le C_2 \end{array} $$

What is the minimum? I found a similar question, [Minimum of $|az_x-bz_y|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/915168), but their $x$ and $y$ are integers. Thus, I guess the question is very different.

I started by computing partials:
\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{a(ax-by)}{|ax-by|}=a\, {\mathrm{sign}(ax-by)}\\
\frac{df}{dy}=\frac{b(by-ax)}{|ax-by|}= b\, {\mathrm{sign}(by-ax)}\\
\end{align}

Having difficulty proceeding further with the Lagrange method. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You calculated $\frac{df}{dx}$ wrong. It is $\pm a$ , depending on the sign of $ax-by$.

Comment: Please see the corrections

Answer (score 10):

There is a simpler way:

$f(x,y) \ge 0$ and $f(0,0)=0$ so the minimum is $0$.

You also have $f\left(x,\dfrac{a}{b}x\right)=0$, which may provide other ways of achieving the minimum. At these points, there may not be a well-defined derivative.

Comment: Are there other minimums. For example, if we  exclude point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Also, do you think there is an analytical solution. Like Lagrange method???

Comment: There are other minima when $\left(x,\dfrac{a}{b}x\right)$. Your derivatives are telling you that when $ax \gt by$ then reduce $x$ or increase $y$, and when $ax \lt by$ then reduce $y$ or increase $x$.