# Minimum of $|ax-by+c|$

Tags: optimization, diophantine-equations, maxima-minima, gcd-and-lcm

> Find the minimum of the function
>
> $$ f(x,y)=|ax-by+c|$$
>
> where $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$ and $x,y \in \mathbb Z$.

The questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919286/minimum-of-fx-y-ax-by) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915168/minimum-of-az-x-bz-y) are similar but they are in cases where $x, y$ are bounded.Taking the partial derivatives,etc. doesn't help. Is there a way to do this efficiently(for a computer program)?

Comment: What is $N$? I guess it isn't the set of natural numbers, since you add $ 0\leq x,y<\infty$

Comment: I have now edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: So, in *standard* notation, $x,y\in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Well ,$ x \geq 0$ so I wrote it as whole numbers....

Comment: Isn't this just a linear Diophantine equation in $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 4):

The smallest positive value that $ax-by$ takes is $\gcd(a,b)$. Finding $x_0$ and $y_0$ for which $ax-by$ is minimal can be done with Euclid's algorithm. Then take an appropriate multiple of $x_0$ and $y_0$ to get as close to $c$ as possible, i.e. multiply both by $\tfrac{c}{\gcd(a,b)}$ rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: "Then take an appropriate multiple of $x_0$ and $y_0$ to get as close to $c$ as possible, i.e. multiply both by $ (\frac{c}{\gcd(x,y)}) $ rounded to the nearest integer."
Could you please explain this in more detail ?

Comment: @nik_97 There was a typo, fixed it now.

Comment: Well, that line is still not clear to me :/ .

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a,b)=d$. Note that for all $k\in \mathbb Z$, there are $x,y\in \mathbb Z$
such that $ax-by=kd$. Also, for all $x,y\in \mathbb Z$, $ax-by$ is of the form $kd$, for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. So the minimum value of $|ax-by+c|$ is the same as the minimum value of the numbers of the form $|kd+c|$. It is obvious that this minimum value is $c$ $(\mod gcd(a,b)).$

Comment: I tried doing this for the equation $|10x-3y-4|$ .I got the answer as minimum =1,whereas the correct answer is 0 (for $x=1,y=2$) . In case you're familiar with C language, I used 
`min = gcd(a,b)%c ;`
where `gcd(a,b)` is calculated recursively using Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo that I fixed. The answer is $c $ $(\mod gcd(a,b))$. Now it  clearly works for your example.